# Error occurred while installing Hive 3.1.3 "Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path"

Tags: hive

I'm getting error while installing hive 3.1.3
When I gave the following command

```bash
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

I get the error

```
Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path
```

I'm installing Hive on hadoop version 3.3.4.